# grid() location with button and frame - Tkinter (Need help)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a  code and I really want to use .grid()

**Interface:**

4 main buttons.
1 button to close the window.
And a title bar to move the window.

The problem is that I can't place them with .grid().
I've been desperately trying to do this for almost an hour now.

**Here's a screen to give you an idea of how I'd like to place them:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWxYI.jpg

The "After" is a photoshop to show you how I see the final rendering.

Can I get some help?
Thank you very much.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk

#Window movement

def Dragging(event):
    x, y = event.x - lastClickX + root.winfo_x(), event.y - lastClickY + root.winfo_y()
    root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x , y))

def SaveLastClickPos(event):
    global lastClickX, lastClickY
    lastClickX = event.x
    lastClickY = event.y

#Root Menu

def main_menu():

   global root
   root = tk.Tk()
   root.overrideredirect(True)
   root.attributes('-topmost', True)
   root.config(background='#302f2f')
   root.minsize(570, 340)
   root.resizable(0,0)

   lastClickX = 0
   lastClickY = 0

   #Title bar and close button

   mainframe = tk.Frame(root, bg='#302f2f')
   mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')

   title_bar = tk.Frame(mainframe, bg='#ff0000', relief='raised', bd=2,highlightthickness=0)
   close_button = tk.Button(title_bar, text='X', command=root.destroy)
   title_bar.grid(row=0, ipadx=200)
   close_button.grid()

   #Buttons 1-2-3-4

   main_fusion_bouton = tk.Button(mainframe, text="4")
   main_fusion_bouton.grid(column= 1, row= 1, padx= 5, pady= 5, ipadx= 10, sticky = "N")

   main_antiduplicate_bouton = tk.Button(mainframe, text="3")
   main_antiduplicate_bouton.grid(column= 2, row= 1, padx= 5, pady= 5, ipadx= 30, sticky = "N")

   main_split_button = tk.Button(mainframe, text="2")
   main_split_button.grid(column= 3, row= 1, ipadx= 19, padx= 5, pady= 5, sticky = "N")

   main_multiply_button = tk.Button(mainframe, text="1")
   main_multiply_button.grid(column= 2, row= 2, pady= 10, ipadx= 19, sticky = "S")

   #Window movement

   title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', Dragging)
   title_bar.bind('<Button-1>', SaveLastClickPos)
   root.mainloop()

main_menu()
```

Comment: To make the title bar appear directly above the buttons, they have to occupy the same column(s).  Since the buttons are in multiple columns, you have to use the `columnspan=` option on the title bar to make it occupy the same columns.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UzZk0lz.png
You're right, unfortunately the bar doesn't take all horizontal

Comment: You would need to use `sticky=` to make the title bar take the full width of its columns, and likewise to make `mainframe` take the full width of the window.  Widgets are not otherwise made any bigger than needed to hold their contents.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. That's perfect. Thank you very much.